# the requested resource is not available. tomcat 7 spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am following up this tutorial 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/building-java-web-application-using-hibernate-with-spring.html
I am having this error >>>> the requested resource could not be found

web.xml file content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>studentHibernateServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servletConfig.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>studentHibernateServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

The controller content

```
package com.github.elizabetht.controller;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;

import com.github.elizabetht.model.Student;
import com.github.elizabetht.model.StudentLogin;
import com.github.elizabetht.service.StudentService;

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Model model) {
        Student student = new Student();        
        model.addAttribute("student", student);     
        return "signup";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String signup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, BindingResult result, Model model) {        
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "signup";
        } else if(studentService.findByUserName(student.getUserName())) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "User Name exists. Try another user name");
            return "signup";
        } else {
            studentService.save(student);
            model.addAttribute("message", "Saved student details");
            return "redirect:login.html";
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {          
        StudentLogin studentLogin = new StudentLogin();     
        model.addAttribute("studentLogin", studentLogin);
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@Valid @ModelAttribute("studentLogin") StudentLogin studentLogin, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            boolean found = studentService.findByLogin(studentLogin.getUserName(), studentLogin.getPassword());
            if (found) {                
                return "success";
            } else {                
                return "failure";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Please assist me I a beginner

Comment: which url are using?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/StudentEnrollmentWithSpring/

Comment: I have also tried this http://localhost:8080/

Comment: Try this:  localhost:8080/StudentEnrollmentWithSpring/signup

Comment: The same result the requested resource is not available

Answer (score 0):

Your dispatcher servlet only listens to `*.html`. You can either call a url having this as its suffix, i.e.:

```
http://localhost::8080/[YourAppName]/[filename].html
```

Or you can change the servlet mapping to something more generic:

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>studentHibernateServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and call i.e.:

```
 http://localhost::8080/[YourAppName]/signup
```

**Update**

Your servlet version is set to 2.5 which is very old. Its [3.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340) at the moment. You might want to update it, to at least [3.0 for Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html), for example. Therefore the tutorial is a little outdated too, search for [Spring 4 MVC](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=spring+4+mvc+tutorial) to find modern ones.

Comment: I am having this error Missing artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.0

Comment: You need to add the [servlet api 3.0.x](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1) as a dependency in pom.xml, and set its [scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to "provided".

Comment: Please how do I know the servlet name

Comment: Used in an mvc project

Comment: See web.xml: "<servlet-name>studentHibernateServlet</servlet-name>".

Comment: Not defining your database parameters can it cause error like resource not found?

Comment: Okay am gradually getting along. Will look for a more recent tutorial.